# Force RStudio to use Python 3.6 and not Python 2.7

Tags: python, rstudio

I want to execute Python scripts in RStudio (this is not about calling Python via reticulate in R scripts this is about running Python scripts in RStudio although reticulate is used, as I see). I have a very simple script called test.py that has the following command:

```
print("test")
```

When I run this command RStudio uses Python 2.7 instead of system default 3.6:

```
> reticulate::repl_python()
Python 2.7.15 (/usr/bin/python)
Reticulate 1.10 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
>>> print("test")
test
>>> 
>>>
```

How to force RStudio to use default system Python version (3.6 in my case) instead of 2.7?

Default version of Python:

```
username@usernameVB:~$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Edit: I found this workaround: go to console and before running Python script execute following commands:

```
> library(reticulate)
> use_python("/usr/bin/python3")
```

Then, execute your Python script (and it picks up correct Python version):

```
> print("test")
[1] "test"
> 
> reticulate::repl_python()
Python 3.6.7 (/usr/bin/python3)
Reticulate 1.10 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
>>>
```

There seems to be an issue raised about this topic:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3385

Answer (score 1):

From this documentation:

https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html

It is not uncommon for several version of Python (and several `conda` or `virtualenv` environments within a given version) to be available on a given system

In this case, the various versions of Python installed on the system will be scanned to see whether one of them includes the Python package (the first version found that satisfies this requirement will be used)

By default, the version of Python found on the system PATH is checked first, and then some other conventional location for Python (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python`, `/opt/local/bin/python`, etc.) are checked. This is what is happening to you.

**There are two ways you can provide hints as to which version of Python should be used:**

a) By setting the value of the **RETICULATE_PYTHON** environment variable to a Python binary.

Note that if you set this environment variable, then the specified version of Python will always be used.

> To set the value of **RETICULATE_PYTHON**, insert this:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = PATH)
```

> into your projects Rprofile, where **PATH** is your preferred Python binary `/usr/bin/python3`

b) By calling one of the these functions **(you are already doing this option)**:

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `use_python()` | Specify the path a specific Python binary |
| `use_virtualenv()` | Specify the directory containing a Python virtualenv |
| `use_condaenv()` | Specify the name of a Conda environment |